# Updating Xamarin project from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Hi I am having difficulty in updating a project using Xamarin.
First I updated my app using the Xamiarin built in tool, this worked great however my project also references MVVMCross (was an older version). So I downloaded an updated version of MVVMCross to 3, built it and switched over the new dll's. The main problem I am seeing right now is I am getting the following error:

```
public void LifetimeChanged (object sender, MvxLifetimeEventArgs e)
    {...}

The type 'System.EventArgs' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 'Sysytem.Runtime' Version=4.0.0.0 etc...
```

I have checked that the class throwing this error does indeed have a reference to both "using System" and "using System.Runtime". I have checked the class in the MVVMCross library has these references also. I cannot see what would be causing this problem? Please any help would be awesome!

Comment: You should tag this with mvvmcross, so that @slodge and other mvvmcross folks see it.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the references and add it again? Sometimes there are old references in the project build (I had the same issue)